# ExtJS Viewport issue

Tags: extjs

Hi
I am designing a viewport.

How can I set only the vertical scrollbar for the viewport?

I am using the style: `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;`, for vertical scroll in the view port.

Comment: Share your code so that we can help you...

Comment: Edit your question when people ask for clarification. This isn't a forum and answers that aren't will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some simple Ext.JS that will give you a Viewport with a single component inside it (using the Fit layout) that scrolls vertically (including some content that should be tall enough to make the scroll bar appear):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
   new Ext.Viewport({
      layout: "fit",
      defaults: {autoScroll: true}, 
      items: [{
         html: "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>" +
               "<p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p><p>demo</p>"
      }]
   })
});
```